# Java (ImageJ): Quick tif unstacking

Tags: java, tiff, imagej

I'm currently iterating through an array of Files where each file is a tif and, if needed, unstacking it to multiple tif files. However my current approach is taking a long time. Could someone please take a look and let me know if there's anything I could do to improve performance?

```
for( File f : stacks ){
    System.out.println( "unstacking \"" + f.getName() + "\"... " );

    ImageStack is = IJ.openImage( f.getAbsolutePath() ).getImageStack();
    int nSlices = is.getSize();
    boolean isStack = true;
    for( int sliceIndex = 1 ; sliceIndex <= nSlices ; sliceIndex++ ){
        String sliceLabel = is.getSliceLabel( sliceIndex );
        if( sliceLabel == null ){
            isStack = false;
            break;
        }

        System.out.println( "\textracting slice \"" + sliceLabel + "\"" );
        IJ.saveAs( new ImagePlus( sliceLabel, is.getProcessor( sliceIndex ) ), "TIF", 
                dir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + sliceLabel );
    }

    if( isStack ){
        f.delete();
        System.out.println( "\tdone!" );
    }else
        System.out.println( "\tnot a stack!" );

}
```

Thank you!

Comment: I don't know ImageJ, so can't help you there. But I assume most of the time is spent decoding/encoding the image data. If you are processing TIFF files only, you could create a special purpose tool that just splits the IFDs, and copies the appropriate parts of each IFD along with corresponding image data, without decoding/encoding the image data in a Java. It should be faster.